Laravel : Get data from query order by asc
I need records in ascending order.
This is my query but it is getting null record first, after that I am getting my other record.
$query = Agent::where('is_super_main_agent', false)
    ->where('is_main_agent', false)
    ->orderBy('atm_active_time', 'ASC');


Try adding ->whereNotNull('data_column')

sry i made mistake in question.Please read it now and try to solve this.

Your query makes sense, but since you're asking a question, it must mean it is not working as intended. Please update your question with an expected and actual result and perhaps error messages if present. Read how do I ask a good question for additional guidance.

you mean you have records where atm_active_time is null?

yes it has null record

If you want to make the null values for atm_active_time showed at the end after sorting, you can use the orderByRaw method along with IS NULL condition
Try below code:
$query = Agent::where('is_super_main_agent', false)
    ->where('is_main_agent', false)
    ->orderByRaw('atm_active_time IS NULL, atm_active_time ASC');

